# form verification dont sent

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code to verify my contact form, issue is what I want is when email has content it will send, without telephone and mobile phone, or telephone has content, email and mobile is empty it will still send my code is below:

```
if (document.forms[0].telephone.value == "" 
    || document.forms[0].email.value == ""
    || document.forms[0].mobile.value == "")
{
    alert("Please provide an email address or phone no. to contact you.");
    selStep(1);
    return;
}
```

but still it asks for the mobile or telephone, has entry it supposed to send.

Comment: Paste your html code

Comment: posted below, please check

Comment: Why paste full code when he gave exactly what a good developer needs for troubleshooting.

Comment: yes, can you help me SZenC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the structure of your if statement. In the statement you essentially say `if(telephone is empty or email is empty or mobile is empty)`. What you need is this

```
if(!(document.forms[0].telephone.value!==""||
     document.forms[0].email.value!==""||
     document.forms[0].mobile.value!=="")){
  alert("Please provide an email address or phone no. to contact you.");
  selStep(1);
  return;
}
```

This will check if any of the fields has data in it, and if that's not the case, it will continue with the if statement.

Comment: thank you very much, that works like a charm, fantastico, cheers, thanks a lot, that was just syntax, thanks a lot your the best

Comment: I just noticed I made a small mistake, it should work in all the major browser, but it's not how it should be. Will update it in a second.

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsValidContact()
{
  if(document.forms[0].telephone.value == "")
  {
    return false;
  }
  if(document.forms[0].email.value == "") 
  {
   return false;
  }
  if(document.forms[0].mobile.value == "")
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}
```

Comment: While suggesting code/solution, at least include a brief about the solution.